# WooCommerce product permalink not working after using woocommerce_sale_flash hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I Added this code at function.php for whatsapp badge after adding this code product links not work but same code work in another site

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'jabir_change_badge', 99, 3 );

function jabir_change_badge( $badge_html, $post, $product ) {
    return "<a href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=9173839776**&text=I%20am%20interested%20 $product->name.'>
                <span class='onsale'>
                    <i class='fa fa-whatsapp fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                </span>
            </a>";
}
```

Product Link:https://theportfolio.cf/motorcycle/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your theme contains the a tag wrapper for each product item as default. That's why when you add another a tag (for WhatsApp), it's and invalid HTML structure because a tag can't contain another a tag.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qdlb.png

You can try to add these hooks to your functions.php to move the a tag open after sale flash

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open');
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply I try through way you suggest it's same as before may be we should change theme.